# How to completely uninstall and remove ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, installation

I recently intalled ArcGIS10.3.1 on my Win10. Initially I was able to use it to do everything before now. Now it comes up with a "crash" window each time I want to add a base-map, open raster data. the report window also doesn't come up anymore. This is why I want to completly uninstall and then reinstall.

However, I am still able to open Vector data but it loads without basemap.

what I have done:
1. Deauthorised and run repair installation.
2. used Uninstall utility on esri site but couldn't remove any ver above ArcGIS10.0

Comment: Whats your error when use raster data? If your directory name is not in english characters you cant import rasters.

Comment: Error message is "ArcGIS for Desktop has encounter a serious appliction error and is unable to continue".I did a fresh install but the error still comes up when i try to add a base map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this instruction](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/installation-guide/uninstalling.htm) to uninstall arcgis.
Also you should uninstall arcgis license manager

Comment: I was able to uninstall the ArcGIS 10.3.1